# Rails: two controllers for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a model User and a corresponding UsersController. Due to project changes, the same, exact functionality for the User model needs to be in the CentersController, with additional functionality for Centers only of course. The UsersController stays as is.

The design question is how to use the UsersController methods (update, edit, create, etc) without replicating them in the CentersController? For example, when a user is updated in the view for Centers, the User controller's Update action will be called, but the viewer should be redirected back to Centers view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what a module, or "mixin" is for. You put the common methods in a module, and include that module into both `UsersController` and `CentersController`.

```
module Foo
  def bar
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include Foo
end

class CentersController < ApplicationController
  include Foo
end
```

Alternatively, put your common code in a controller, and inherit from that controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def bar
  end
end

class UsersController < FooController
end

class CentersController < FooController
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was heading towards the proposed solution, but all I really need to change is the redirect_to sentence in the UsersController: instead of users_path, it would be center_path if the Center view initiated this. Is there another recommended (i.e. RESTful) way using routes or helpers?